# How to pair an iPhone?

Tags: mount, iphone

I already installed ifuse via this code:

```
sudo apt-get install ifuse libimobiledevice-utils
```

and then when I want to pair via this code:

```
idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
```

I get the following reply:

will@Will-PC:~$ idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
usbmuxd_get_device_list: error opening socket!
No device found, is it plugged in?

And yes I did have my phone unlocked the whole process.

Help would be appreciated!